# PromQL - how combine "sum_over_time" with "by"

Tags: grafana, promql

I'm trying to write a query that will return the following information:

for metric m1 (of type counter)  - return the sum of values, grouped by (p1,p2) in a sliding window of 1h.

I think the base should be something like:

```
sum_over_time(m1[1h])
```

but this cannot be grouped by (p1,p2)

One way to do the grouping is by

```
sum(sum_over_time(m1[1h])) by (p1, p2)
```

but i'm not sure if adding the external sum here, just in order to group, is the way to go.

Another possibility it to do:

```
topk(100, sum_over_time(m1[1h])) by (p1, p2)
```

but in this case the grouping doesn't seem to happen right, as the results contain a lot of rows with the same (p1,p2) and different in some other labels (p3,p4)

what is the correct way to sum a metric, in a sliding window, by some lables?

Comment: To me `sum(sum_over_time(m1[1h])) by (p1, p2)` makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap sum_over_time  into sum  as a workaround and query will work smoothly.

E.g.:

```
topk(100, sum(sum_over_time(m1[1h])) by(p1, p2))
```